# Hide an option element if a matching value is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-select

One day I had a problem with PHP and a super guy resolved my problem, this time I learn JavaScript, and I'm really stuck on a project.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xasal/8c0kdqm4/5/

As you see, I have 2 selectors, on the left, the user see his characters, at the right, he can chose to switch his "race", the problem is I want JavaScript to run something when the guy selects his character at the left to compare with the right one and automatically delete the option if it's for the same race.. I made the functions for all to disappear, the only problem is the compare value... and when I think my code is nice I have issues in the dev console of unexpected end or syntax

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Sorry if it's kinda easy for you I'm really new :x

```
<select id="charSelect" name="charSelection">
      <option value="Knight" selected="selected"><span id="charName">Gooffy</span> - <span class="charJob" onclick="detectChanges()">Knight</span> - lv.<span id="charLvl">175</span></option>
      <option value="NightShadow"><span>Soul</span> - <span class="charJob" onclick="detectChanges()">NightShadow</span> - lv.<span>175</span></option>
    <option value="Rogue"><span>Veli</span> - <span class="charJob" onclick="detectChanges()">Rogue</span> - lv.<span>175</span></option>
      </select>
    </section>
            <input type="submit" value="Change my class to">
    <section class="rightSelect">
      <select class="jobSelect" name="jobSelection">
      <option value="titan" id="titan" class="charJobChange" selected="selected">Titan</option>
      <option value="knight" id="knight" class="charJobChange">Knight</option>
      <option value="healer" id="healer" class="charJobChange">Healer</option>
      <option value="mage" id="mage" class="charJobChange">Mage</option>
      <option value="rogue" id="rogue" class="charJobChange">Rogue</option>
      <option value="sorcerer" id="sorcerer" class="charJobChange">Sorcerer</option>
      <option value="nightshadow" id="nightshadow" class="charJobChange">NightShadow</option>
      </select>
```

```
function removeNS() {  // example with Hide NS = nightshadow
   $('#nightshadow').hide();
   console.log("loaded");
}

function selectedCh(){
  if($("#leftSelect select").find("option:selected").val() == "NightShadow") {
  removeNS();
}
selectedCh();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Anton. This is a good first question. Don't forget to accept an answer if you found it helpful. Cheers.

Comment: @r3wt Thank you realy much for your welcomingsss ! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

I called the function in `onchange="selectedCh()"` of left select box.

```
function selectedCh(){

  // to get selected option in left select box in lowercase
  var selectedtitem = $(".leftSelect select").find("option:selected").val().toLowerCase();
  
  // to get total number of options in right select box
  var oplen = $(".rightSelect select option").length;

  // enable all option in right select box
  $(".rightSelect select option").show();

  // Loop for checking the selected option equals to any option in right select box 
  for(i=1;i<=oplen;i++){
    if($(".rightSelect select option:nth-child("+i+")").val() == selectedtitem){

        // to hide if equals in right select box option
        $(".rightSelect select option:nth-child("+i+")").hide();
    }
  }
}

// to check first run the code
selectedCh();
```

**Working demo**

```js
function selectedCh(){
  var selectedtitem = $(".leftSelect select").find("option:selected").val().toLowerCase();
  var oplen = $(".rightSelect select option").length;
  $(".rightSelect select option").show();
  for(i=1;i<=oplen;i++){
    if($(".rightSelect select option:nth-child("+i+")").val() == selectedtitem){
        $(".rightSelect select option:nth-child("+i+")").hide();
    }
  }
}
selectedCh();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="leftSelect">
  <select id="charSelect" name="charSelection" onchange="selectedCh()">
    <option value="Knight" selected="selected"><span id="charName">Gooffy</span> - <span class="charJob" onclick="detectChanges()">Knight</span> - lv.<span id="charLvl">175</span></option>
    <option value="NightShadow"><span>Soul</span> - <span class="charJob">NightShadow</span> - lv.<span>175</span></option>
    <option value="Rogue"><span>Veli</span> - <span class="charJob" >Rogue</span> - lv.<span>175</span></option>
  </select>
</section>

<section class="rightSelect">
  <select class="jobSelect" name="jobSelection">
    <option value="titan" id="titan" class="charJobChange" selected="selected">Titan</option>
    <option value="knight" id="knight" class="charJobChange">Knight</option>
    <option value="healer" id="healer" class="charJobChange">Healer</option>
    <option value="mage" id="mage" class="charJobChange">Mage</option>
    <option value="rogue" id="rogue" class="charJobChange">Rogue</option>
    <option value="sorcerer" id="sorcerer" class="charJobChange">Sorcerer</option>
    <option value="nightshadow" id="nightshadow" class="charJobChange">NightShadow</option>
  </select>
</section>
```

Comment: I add all desciption in a code one by one. if any doubt comment me.

Comment: Omg man ty realy much for your comments on your code it haves so much value for me thank you for your effort, btw it's working perfectly!

Comment: so ("+i+") = any string inside of option:nth-child? :)

Comment: Yes it get i value from 1 to the length of options . thats it get all options .

Answer (score 2):

> Hide option if value == 'option 3'

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectName">
    <option value="option 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option 3">Option 3 (hide on chnage)</option>
    <option value="option 4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option 5">Option 5</option>
</select>

<script>
    $('#selectName').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'option 3') {
            $('option[value="option 3"]',this).hide();
        } else {
            $('option[value="option 3"]',this).show();
        }
    }).trigger('change');;
</script>
```

Comment: interestly! thank you for this it's not exactly what i want but it can help me in future stucks lol!! ty for your awesome answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a query selector for find the matching option and hide it. Here is a minimal example:

```js
var charSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="charSelection"]');
var jobSelect = document.querySelector('select[name="jobSelection"]');

charSelect.addEventListener('change', function(){
  // Unhide any hidden options
  jobSelect.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(opt=>opt.style.display = null);
  // Hide the option that matches the above selected one
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
  jobSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${value}"]`).style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<select name="charSelection">
  <option value="Knight" selected="selected">Knight</option>
  <option value="NightShadow">NightShadow</option>
  <option value="Rogue">Rogue</option>
</select>


<select name="jobSelection">
  <option value="titan" selected="selected">Titan</option>
  <option value="knight">Knight</option>
  <option value="healer">Healer</option>
  <option value="mage">Mage</option>
  <option value="rogue">Rogue</option>
  <option value="sorcerer">Sorcerer</option>
  <option value="nightshadow">NightShadow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works realy well, the only problem is, when the page loads and it preselects (selected="selected) Gooffy the knight, the user can see Knight, but whenever you switch it's ok :)) i learned a lot today thank you for your help !